# Syntax Error while String concatenating with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to push the Javascript object using a loop And Getting the value of input using jQuery.

```js
var data = {name: "Grace"};

$("#test").on('change', function () {
  
      console.log($('"#test'+1+'T"').val());
  
      for(var i=1; i<= 2; i++){
        data['Thomas'+i+'Shelby'] = $('"#test'+i+'T"').val();
      }
      console.log(data);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="test1T">
<input type="text" id="test2T">
<input type="text" id="test">
```

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "#test1T"

**Expected Output: **

If user input *Arthur* in `#test1T`, *John* in `#test2T` and *Micheal* in `#test`.

Then It should console log following object:

```
{
 name: "Grace",
 Thomas1Shelby: "Arthur",
 Thomas2Shelby: "John",
}
```

Comment: Where is the `Micheal `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's error in query selector. Don't put `"` inside.

change `$('"#test'+i+'T"').val()`
to be `$('#test'+i+'T').val()`

```js
var data = {name: "Grace"};

$("#test").on('change', function () {
  
      console.log($('#test'+1+'T').val());
  
      for(var i=1; i<= 2; i++){
        data['Thomas'+i+'Shelby'] = $('#test'+i+'T').val();
      }
      console.log(data);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test1T">
<input type="text" id="test2T">
<input type="text" id="test">
```

Answer (score 1):

Quotes issues.
A valid ID selector would look like

`$('#test1T')` or `$('#test'+i+'T')`

I suggest template literals

```js
const data = {
  name: "Grace"
};

$("#test").on('change', function() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    data[`Thomas${i}Shelby`] = $(`#test${i}T`).val();
  }
  console.log(data);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="test1T">
<input type="text" id="test2T">
<input type="text" id="test">
```